# Are exported (installed) cmake targets distributable?

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

I'm working on a project with a lot of external dependencies, which are included in the project tree. I would like to pre-build all of the dependencies and share the importable targets within the project tree.

I was planning to use cmake install with a CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in the source tree, and use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to reference it for find_package. However, I'm beginning to wonder how maintainable this strategy is going to be? For example here's something I noticed in one of the installed cmake scripts:

**${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake:**

```
set_target_properties(glfw PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;dl;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;-lpthread"
)
```

It seems really suspicious to me that all of those link libraries are fully resolved to paths on the host machine.

I guess the question is: Are cmake installs to a prefix meant to be distributable and this is just a bad example, or are they meant to be tied to the machine you "install" them on? Ie. Is prefix really meant to just relocate where on the system things are supposed to be "installed", and my hope to use it as a shared package manager likely to be problematic?

Comment: You shouldn't share the files cmake installs by copying them and sending them to someone else. It is fine to consume them locally

Comment: As for your question, if you want to make a fully distributable executable, the best way is still static linking.

Comment: If you are trying to package your project into something the end user can use, see [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html)

Comment: @Justin technically, it's a team of people working on a product together. We're not distributing an API that end users would consume, unless you're saying my team is the end user... In which case I still don't really think I want to be "installing" anything on anyone's machine, rather having all of the dependencies as part of the project so they can all be linked to easily (even if they are all built as static libs as "Some programmer dude" pointed out.

Comment: Either have everyone run cmake themselves, or enforce a common system setup, perhaps through a VM. Check out [conan](https://conan.io/) or [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) or one of the other package managers

Comment: Everyone will run cmake, but I don't necessarily want everyone to rebuild all of the dependencies from source. I'd like to at least prebuild some of the dependencies and have targets that the other users can import.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *EXPORT*'ed CMake targets can be "distributable", but the project should follow some principles for achieve that.

If you link with a (external) library, but do not want export file to contain absolute path to it, then **do not pass absolute path directly** to `target_link_libraries`.

In case a linked library is *shipped with a compiler* (e.g. `m` or `rt`), things are simple: just pass the library's **name** to the `target_link_libraries`.

In case a linked library YYY comes from **other package** and is detected by `find_package(YYY)`, this implies several things:

1. Script `FindYYY.cmake` or `YYYConfig.cmake` should return *IMPORTED* target. If this is not true, you may try to wrap its results into *IMPORTED* target.
2. `target_link_libraries` should use this *IMPORTED* target.
3. Script `XXXConfig.cmake`, shipped with *your project*, should use [find_dependency(YYY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) for discover a library on a user machine.
4. For `find_dependency(YYY)` work, a user machine should have `FindYYY.cmake` or `YYYConfig.cmake` script. Alternatively, you may ship `FindYYY.cmake` with your project, and adjust `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable before `find_dependency()` call (in your `XXXConfig.cmake`).

Comment: Thanks. Though, in your second paragraph, I don't follow. Do I need to edit the third_party cmake script? In every case I can think of all of the target_libraries are other targets and not paths to libs.

Comment: "Do I need to edit the third_party cmake script?" - This would be not recommended. If third-party script `FindYYY.cmake` doesn't provide *IMPORTED* target but provides variables, you may create (after call to `find_package(YYY)`) *IMPORTED* (or even *INTERFACE* *IMPORTED*) target by yourself, and set its properties according to these variables. The same should be done in your `XXXConfig.cmake` script after call `find_dependency(YYY)`.

Comment: No, I meant... in regards to "do not pass absolute path directly" to target_link_libraries. I can't really control what 3rd party libraries do there.

For example: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L185

This shows the cmake that resulted in the absolute paths posted in the question.

Comment: Using absolute paths in a 3d party project means just that export targets of **that project** are not relocatable. You still may have your own package and its export targets to be relocatable. (Assuming you use `find_package(GLFW)` and `find_dependency(GLFW)` for discover glfw libraries).

Comment: The problem is almost all of the third_party libraries will use some find_package(AAA) to locate dependencies on the system, and the general FindAAA scripts (included with cmake) create non-relocatable paths. Is there a setting to tweak that?  And since their dependencies are transitively consumed, it creates a nightmare of non-relocatable targets.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135785/correctly-set-the-location-of-imported-cmake-targets-for-an-installed-package/56135786#56135786