# correctly set the location of imported cmake targets for an installed package

Tags: cmake

I would like to be able to import targets from an installed library but
when using:

```
install(TARGETS
        foobar
        EXPORT foobarLibTargets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

cmake generates a *foobarLibTargets.cmake* containing an absolute path:

```
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "/where/I/happened/to/build/libfoobar.so"
        IMPORTED_SONAME_NOCONFIG "libfoobar.so"
)
```

Such that a build using the imported target from the installation will fail as the path does not exist.

**Q How can I get it to use the correct relative location instead?**

This would be equivalent to:

```
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@/libfoobar.so")
```

If I look at another project which does something similar but works it has:

```
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
         IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libfoobar.so"
         IMPORTED_SONAME_RELEASE "libfoobar.so"
)
```

---

Here are some example files that reproduce the issue:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(FOOBAR VERSION 1.2.3)
set(VERSION 1.2.3)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt/foobar" CACHE PATH "Install path prefix" FORCE)

add_library(foobar SHARED
  foobar.cpp
)

set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY 0)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "foobar")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${VERSION})
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}")

include(CPack)

# Indicate the content of the distribution pakcages
install(FILES
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foobar.h
  DESTINATION include
)
install(TARGETS
  foobar
  EXPORT foobarLibTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
set(ConfigFileInstallDir lib/cmake/foobar)
set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR include)
set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib)
message(STATUS "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
configure_package_config_file(foobarConfig.cmake.in
     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}"
    PATH_VARS INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR)
write_basic_package_version_file(
   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfigVersion.cmake"
   VERSION "${VERSION}"
   COMPATIBILITY ExactVersion)
export(EXPORT foobarLibTargets
       FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake")
install(EXPORT foobarLibTargets
        FILE foobarTargets.cmake
        DESTINATION lib/cmake)
install(FILES
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfig.cmake"
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarConfigVersion.cmake"
   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}")
```

foobarConfig.cmake.in:

```
set(FOOBAR_VERSION @VERSION@)

@PACKAGE_INIT@

set_and_check(FOOBAR_INCLUDE_DIR "@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR@")
set_and_check(FOOBAR_LIBRARY "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@/libfoobar.so")
set_and_check(FOOBAR_LIBRARY_DIR "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@")
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake")

# workaround - correct absolute path in the above
# this shouldn't be necessary (hence this question)
#set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
#  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@/libfoobar.so"
#)
```

foobar.h:

```
void hello();
```

foobar.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
   std::cerr << "hello world\n";
}
```

useFoo.cmake (a CMakeLists.txt for an example project using the installed library):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(useFoo VERSION 1.2.3)
set(VERSION 1.2.3)

find_package(foobar)
file(GENERATE OUTPUT foobar-gen CONTENT "<TARGET_FILE:foobar>=$<TARGET_FILE:foobar>\n")

message(STATUS "FOOBAR_LIBRARY_DIR=${FOOBAR_LIBRARY_DIR}")
message(STATUS "FOOBAR_INCLUDE_DIR=${FOOBAR_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

build.sh (build and use the installation package):

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf target
mkdir target
cd target
cmake .. &&
make &&
cpack -G TGZ
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "doh!"
   exit 1
fi

cd ..
rm -rf install
mkdir install
cd install
tar -xvzf ../target/foobar-1.2.3.tar.gz
cp ../useFoo.cmake CMakeLists.txt
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`pwd`/opt/foobar/lib/cmake:`pwd`/opt/foobar/lib/cmake/foobar
cmake .
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "doh!"
   exit 1
fi
cat foobar-gen
```

The output of `cat foobar-gen` is:

```
<TARGET_FILE:foobar>=/where/I/happened/to/build/libfoobar.so
```

I would like it to be:

```
<TARGET_FILE:foobar>=/where/I/actually/installed/libfoobar.so
```

Which it becomes if I uncomment the workaround.
**Is there a way which avoids the workaround?**

The related question - [Strange issue with variables in a config-file cmake package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189739/strange-issue-with-variables-in-a-config-file-cmake-package) - has similar code which both reproduces this issue and adds another one on top.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941571/are-exported-installed-cmake-targets-distributable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only after instrumenting the source of cmake itself was I finally able to track this down.

The export and install commands are both capable of generating cmake files for targets.
The export command e.g.:

```
export(EXPORT foobarLibTargets
       FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake")
```

creates a Targets.cmake referencing the build tree.

The install command e.g.:

```
install(EXPORT foobarLibTargets
        FILE foobarTargets.cmake
        DESTINATION lib/cmake)
```

creates a Targets.cmake referencing the relocatable install location.

This is essentially what @J-Christophe meant by saying that two files were installed and the wrong one was picked up.

I had wrongly assumed that the install command was only responsible for installing files and the export command was only responsible for generating them.

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/export.html) makes sense now

> export(EXPORT  [NAMESPACE ] [FILE ])
>
> The file created by this command is specific to the build tree and
>   should never be installed. See the install(EXPORT) command to export
>   targets from an installation tree.

The workaround I had previously is no longer necesary.
For reference this was to explicitly set the correct location in the package's Config.cmake as in:

```
set(FOOBAR_VERSION @VERSION@)

@PACKAGE_INIT@

set_and_check(FOOBAR_INCLUDE_DIR "@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR@")
set_and_check(FOOBAR_LIBRARY "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@/libfoobar.so")
set_and_check(FOOBAR_LIBRARY_DIR "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@")
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foobarLibTargets.cmake")

# workaround - correct absolute path in the above
# this shouldn't be necessary!
set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG  "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@/libfoobar.so"
)
```

Answer (score 6):

The main issue is that the two files `foobarLibTargets.cmake` and `foobarTargets.cmake` were both installed and the wrong one was picked up.

You will find below an improved project along with remarks to better organize the build system.

#### ChangeLog summarizing edits

- 2019-05-25

  - Create GitHub project to streamline reuse and adaptation. See https://github.com/jcfr/stackoverflow-56135785-answer
  - Rename project and source directory from `foobar` to `FooBarLib`, update Suggestions section accordingly
  - Improve `build.sh`
  - Updated suggestions (`CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX` should be absolute)
  - RPM:

    - Add support for building RPM package using `make package`
    - Update `build.sh` to display content of RPM package

#### Remarks

- Two config files should be generated:

  - one for the build tree: this allow user of your project to directly build against your project and import targets
  - one for the install tree (which also end up being packaged)
- Do not force the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`
- <s>`CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX` should NOT be set to an absolute directory</s>
- <s>For sake of consistency, use `foobarTargets` instead of `foobarLibTargets`</s>
- `<projecname_uc>` placeholder used below correspond to the name of the project upper-cased (`ABC` instead of `abc`)
- To allow configuring your project when vendorized along other one, prefer variable with `<projecname_uc>_`. This means `<projecname_uc>_INSTALL_LIBRARY_DIR` is better than `LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR`.
- To allow user of the project to configure `*_INSTALL_DIR` variables, wrap them around `if(DEFINED ...)`
- Consistently use variables (e.g `LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR` should always be used instead of `lib`)
- Prefer naming variable `<projecname_uc>_INSTALL_*_DIR` instead of `<projecname_uc>_*_INSTALL_DIR`, it make it easier to know the purpose of the variable when reading the code.
- Since version is already associated with the project, there is no need to set `VERSION` variable. Instead, you can use `PROJECT_VERSION` or `FOOBAR_VERSION`
- If starting a new project, prefer the most recent CMake version. CMake 3.13 instead of CMake 3.7
- Introduced variable `<projecname_uc>_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR`
- `<project_name>Targets.cmake` should not be installed using `install(FILES ...)`,  it is already associated with an install rule
- conditionally set `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH`, it is valid only on Linux
- `<project_name>Config.cmake.in`:

  - there is no need to set `FOOBAR_LIBRARY`, this information is already associated with the exported `foobar` target
  - FOOBAR_LIBRARY_DIR is also not needed, this information is already associated with the exported `foobar` target
  - instead of setting FOOBAR_INCLUDE_DIR, the command `target_include_directories` should be used
  - remove setting of `FOOBAR_VERSION`, the generate version file already takes care of setting the version.
- always specify ARCHIVE, LIBRARY and RUNTIME when declaring install rules for target. It avoid issue when switching library type. One less thing to think about.
- always specify component with your install rule. It allows user of your project to selectively install part of it only development component or only runtime one, ...
- initializing `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is also important,  it ensures the generated Targets file are associated with a configuration (instead of having the suffix `-noconfig.cmake`)

#### Suggested changes

Generally speaking, I recommend to have a source tree, a build tree and install tree. The files posted below assumed the following layout:

```
./build.sh

./FooBarLib/FooBarLibConfig.cmake.in
./FooBarLib/CMakeLists.txt
./FooBarLib/foobar.cpp
./FooBarLib/foobar.h

./FooBarLib-build

./FooBarLib-install

./useFoo/CMakeLists.txt
./useFoo-build
```

- build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -xeu
set -o pipefail

script_dir=$(cd $(dirname $0) || exit 1; pwd)

project_name=FooBarLib
archive_name=${project_name}

# cleanup ${project_name}-build
cd $script_dir
rm -rf ${project_name}-build
mkdir ${project_name}-build
cd ${project_name}-build

# configure, build and package ${project_name}
cmake ../${project_name}
make
make package # equivalent to running "cpack -G TGZ" and "cmake -G RPM"

# extract ${project_name} archive
cd $script_dir
rm -rf ${project_name}-install
mkdir ${project_name}-install
cd ${project_name}-install
tar -xvzf ../${project_name}-build/${archive_name}-1.2.3.tar.gz

# cleanup useFoo-build
cd $script_dir
rm -rf useFoo-build
mkdir useFoo-build
cd useFoo-build

cpack_install_prefix=/opt

# configure useFoo
cmake -D${project_name}_DIR=$script_dir/${project_name}-install${cpack_install_prefix}/lib/cmake/${project_name}/ ../useFoo

cat foobar-gen

# display content of RPM. If command "rpmbuild" is available, RPM package is expected.
if command -v rpmbuild &> /dev/null; then
  rpm -qlp $script_dir/${project_name}-build/${archive_name}-1.2.3.rpm
fi
```

- FooBarLib/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(FooBarLib VERSION 1.2.3)

if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/")
endif()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set a default build type if none was specified
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  message(STATUS "Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  # Set the possible values of build type for cmake-gui
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release" "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable controls the prefix used to generate the following files:
#  <export_config_name>ConfigVersion.cmake
#  <export_config_name>Config.cmake
#  <export_config_name>Targets.cmake
# and it also used to initialize FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR value.
set(export_config_name ${PROJECT_NAME})

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(NOT DEFINED FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR include)
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_BIN_DIR)
  set(FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_BIN_DIR bin)
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_LIBRARY_DIR)
  set(FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_LIBRARY_DIR lib)
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR)
  set(FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_LIBRARY_DIR}/cmake/${export_config_name})
endif()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(headers
  foobar.h
  )

# Install rule for headers
install(
  FILES ${headers}
  DESTINATION ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}
  COMPONENT Development
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
add_library(foobar SHARED
  foobar.cpp
  )

target_include_directories(foobar
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${FooBarLib_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}>
  )

install(
  TARGETS foobar
  EXPORT ${export_config_name}Targets
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_LIBRARY_DIR} COMPONENT Development
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_LIBRARY_DIR} COMPONENT RuntimeLibraries
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_BIN_DIR} COMPONENT RuntimeLibraries
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure <export_config_name>ConfigVersion.cmake common to build and install tree
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
set(config_version_file ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${export_config_name}ConfigVersion.cmake)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${config_version_file}
  VERSION "${FooBarLib_VERSION}"
  COMPATIBILITY ExactVersion
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Export '<export_config_name>Targets.cmake' for a build tree
export(
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${export_config_name}Targets.cmake"
  )

# Configure '<export_config_name>Config.cmake' for a build tree
set(build_config ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${export_config_name}Config.cmake)
configure_package_config_file(
  ${export_config_name}Config.cmake.in 
  ${build_config}
  INSTALL_DESTINATION "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Export '<export_config_name>Targets.cmake' for an install tree
install(
  EXPORT ${export_config_name}Targets
  FILE ${export_config_name}Targets.cmake
  DESTINATION ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR}
  )

set(install_config ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/${export_config_name}Config.cmake)
configure_package_config_file(
  ${export_config_name}Config.cmake.in 
  ${install_config}
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR}
  )

# Install config files
install(
  FILES ${config_version_file} ${install_config}
  DESTINATION "${FOOBARLIB_INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR}"
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate package

set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY 0)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}")

# Setting this variable also impacts the layout of TGZ.
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt")

# Setting CPACK_SOURCE_* and CPACK_GENERATOR allow to have "make package" generates
# the expected archive.

# Disable source generator enabled by default
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TBZ2 OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable to build TBZ2 source packages" FORCE)
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ  OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable to build TGZ source packages" FORCE)
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TZ OFF CACHE BOOL "Enable to build TZ source packages" FORCE)

# Select generators
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
  set(CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ")
  find_program(RPMBUILD_PATH rpmbuild)
  if(RPMBUILD_PATH)
    list(APPEND CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
  endif()
elseif(APPLE)
  # ...
endif()

include(CPack)
```

- FooBarLib/FooBarLibConfig.cmake.in

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

set(export_config_name "@export_config_name@")

set_and_check(${export_config_name}_TARGETS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${export_config_name}Targets.cmake")

include(${${export_config_name}_TARGETS})
```

- useFoo/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(useFoo VERSION 1.2.3)

find_package(FooBarLib REQUIRED)

file(GENERATE OUTPUT foobar-gen CONTENT "<TARGET_FILE:foobar>=$<TARGET_FILE:foobar>\n")

get_target_property(foobar_INCLUDE_DIR foobar INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "foobar_INCLUDE_DIR=${foobar_INCLUDE_DIR}")

get_target_property(imported_location foobar IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
get_filename_component(foobar_LIBRARY_DIR ${imported_location} DIRECTORY)
message(STATUS "foobar_LIBRARY_DIR=${foobar_LIBRARY_DIR}")
```

#### Output of build.sh

```
./build.sh 
+ set -o pipefail
+++ dirname ./build.sh
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ script_dir=/tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer
+ project_name=FooBarLib
+ archive_name=FooBarLib
+ cd /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer
+ rm -rf FooBarLib-build
+ mkdir FooBarLib-build
+ cd FooBarLib-build
+ cmake ../FooBarLib
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-build
+ make
Scanning dependencies of target foobar
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/foobar.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libfoobar.so
[100%] Built target foobar
+ make package
[100%] Built target foobar
Run CPack packaging tool...
CPack: Create package using TGZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: FooBarLib
CPack: - Install project: FooBarLib
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-build/FooBarLib-1.2.3.tar.gz generated.
CPack: Create package using RPM
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: FooBarLib
CPack: - Install project: FooBarLib
CPack: Create package
-- CPackRPM:Debug: Using CPACK_RPM_ROOTDIR=/tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM
CPackRPM: Will use GENERATED spec file: /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/SPECS/foobarlib.spec
CPack: - package: /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-build/FooBarLib-1.2.3.rpm generated.
+ cd /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer
+ rm -rf FooBarLib-install
+ mkdir FooBarLib-install
+ cd FooBarLib-install
+ tar -xvzf ../FooBarLib-build/FooBarLib-1.2.3.tar.gz
opt/
opt/include/
opt/include/foobar.h
opt/lib/
opt/lib/libfoobar.so
opt/lib/cmake/
opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/
opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibTargets.cmake
opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibTargets-release.cmake
opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibConfigVersion.cmake
opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibConfig.cmake
+ cd /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer
+ rm -rf useFoo-build
+ mkdir useFoo-build
+ cd useFoo-build
+ cpack_install_prefix=/opt
+ cmake -DFooBarLib_DIR=/tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-install/opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/ ../useFoo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- foobar_INCLUDE_DIR=/tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-install/opt/include
-- foobar_LIBRARY_DIR=/tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-install/opt/lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/useFoo-build
+ cat foobar-gen
<TARGET_FILE:foobar>=/tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-install/opt/lib/libfoobar.so
+ command -v rpmbuild
+ rpm -qlp /tmp/stackoverflow-56135785-answer/FooBarLib-build/FooBarLib-1.2.3.rpm
/opt
/opt/include
/opt/include/foobar.h
/opt/lib
/opt/lib/cmake
/opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib
/opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibConfig.cmake
/opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibConfigVersion.cmake
/opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibTargets-release.cmake
/opt/lib/cmake/FooBarLib/FooBarLibTargets.cmake
/opt/lib/libfoobar.so
```

Comment: I have only one Targets.cmake file being generated. There is no FoobarTargets.cmake only FoobarLibTargets.cmake. A confusion here may come from us using project names that include lib. So a shared library project is FoobarLib rather than Foobar. This is not just hungarian notation but servers to distinguish FoobarApi from FoobarLib which implements it.

Comment: If I set CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX to a relative path e.g. set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "opt/foobar"). I get:

CMake Error at /home/brucea/Downloads/cmake-3.9.0/Modules/CPackRPM.cmake:1023 (file):
  file RELATIVE_PATH must be passed a full path to the directory: opt/rtm
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/brucea/Downloads/cmake-3.9.0/Modules/CPackRPM.cmake:1875 (cpack_rpm_prepare_relocation_paths)
  /home/brucea/Downloads/cmake-3.9.0/Modules/CPackRPM.cmake:2747 (cpack_rpm_generate_package)

Comment: This was on oversight, you are correct, CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX should be an absolute path. i will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Using `FoobarLib` instead of `Foobar` is not a problem. In the CMakeLists.txt I provided, you can do so by replacing `FOOBAR` with `FOOBARLIB`, and `foobar` with `foobarlib`. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The answer has been updated, along with a summary of the changes, a RPM package is also generated when calling "make package". 
After calling "build.sh", the content of the RPM package is also displayed.

Comment: @BruceAdams Let me know if you have any other questions or if the answer should be improved in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions here are misleading. It's by design working that way: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/f46c67de0e16293a40bbbade18aa7cee9edb02b0/Source/cmExportInstallFileGenerator.cxx#L184-L192

So if the `DESTINATION` in the `install(EXPORT ...)` statement is an absolute path, then hardcode it as absolute path in the exported package config files. Otherwise, generate the path dynamically using `_IMPORT_PREFIX`.